# ASP Repeater not showing data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, pager, asprepeater

I'm trying to get an alphabet pager working in `GridView`. It does work, but only one letter shows up in the repeater that I'm using to show the letters. I've read other posts and looked at my code and it seems like it should be working, but it's not. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my html

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAlphabets" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Selected"))%>' OnClick="Alphabet_Click"/>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAlpha" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Selected"))%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is my code behind

```
Private Sub GenerateAlphabets()
    Dim alphabets As New List(Of ListItem)()
    Dim alphabet As New ListItem
    alphabet.Value = "ALL"
    alphabet.Selected = alphabet.Value.Equals(ViewState("CurrentAlphabet"))
    alphabets.Add(alphabet)
    For i As Integer = 65 To 90
        alphabet = New ListItem()
        alphabet.Value = [Char].ConvertFromUtf32(i)
        alphabet.Selected =   alphabet.Value.Equals(ViewState("CurrentAlphabet"))
        alphabets.Add(alphabet)
    Next

    rptAlphabets.DataSource = alphabets
    rptAlphabets.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I'm using most of the code from an aspsnippets method.

**EDIT** : 
I'm calling the GenerateAlphabets from my `Page_Load`

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try

        ClearMessages()
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            ViewState("CurrentAlphabet") = "ALL"
            Me.GenerateAlphabets()
            BindGrids()
            BindDropDownListBoxes()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.HandleError(ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Do an experiment, [set a breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4607yxb0(v=vs.100).aspx) at `rptAlphabets.DataSource = alphabets` and inspect the state of `alphabets`. I bet you'll be surprised at what you see.

Comment: @mason I did that. And alphabets contains all the letters and "ALL". As I step through, the datasource picks it up too

Comment: Where are you calling GenerateAlphabets() from? Is there a postback on your page?

Comment: @Kami I did an edit. I'm calling it from the Page_load and yes there is a PostBack

Comment: remove Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Selected"))%>' and they will display. Your viewstate appears to be false at all times.

Comment: Your ViewState is set to "ALL" so it only works for the first item which is "ALL". Add ViewState("CurrentAlphabet") = [Char].ConvertFromUtf32(i) in our for loop.

Comment: @Kami The ViewState is set to "ALL" so that when the page loads, I get all the records. But i had to just make it visible, for some reason it was always false like you said. It now works, THANKS!!

Comment: That's fine but you have to change it with each alphabet being added to your list otherwise you are always checking against "ALL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your LinkButton code like this.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn1" runat="server" 
        Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>' 
        Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Selected")) = False %>'
        OnClick="Alphabet_Click"/>
```

Reason: You are hiding all LinkButtons that are not currently selected. You should be showing them instead.

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error. "Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement. I just removed the visible statement and it works like how I thought it should work

Comment: but then it would show link button for the selected letter too. try this edit. I thought it was C#. my bad

Comment: I see what you mean!!